# Groovy Array.pop() returns No signature of method: java.lang.String.pop()

Tags: java, groovy

I am using groovy in jenkins and there is this string that i need to get the last word in it. Let just say the string is `STATUS = "EXECUTE SIT"`. So what I did was to split the string so that I will get an array `STATUS.split()` and then pop so that i can get SIT string `STATUS.split().pop()`. But it returns an error `No signature of method: java.lang.String.pop()` I am not that familiar with Groovy or Java so I don't really know if I'm using these methods correctly.

Comment: I would recommend you assign the split to an array: `String[] tokens = STATUS.split()` then do the pop `tokens.pop()`

Comment: @MadaManu An array has a `pop` method?

Comment: You're right! No pop on array! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the error you're getting is actually `No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.pop() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`. Note the `[L` - this means you have an array, not a List.

[`split()`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#split()) returns an array of Strings (`String[]`) which doesn't support using `pop()` or many other of Groovy's enhancements.

Instead use [`tokenize()`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#tokenize()) which returns a `List`. Once you have a list, you can use [`pop()`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#pop()) or more appropriately, [`last()`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#last()). `pop()` was changed in Groovy 2.5 to remove the first item instead of the last. Use [`removeLast()`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#removeLast()) if you actually want to remove the last item.

```
"EXECUTE SIT".tokenize().last()
===> SIT
```